# How can I have a pipe with multiple communication types?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Say I have this code:

```
import Control.Monad.State hiding (StateT)
import Control.Proxy

server :: (Proxy p, Monad m) => Int -> Server p Int Bool (StateT Int m) ()
server = runIdentityK loop
    where loop arg = do
        currMax <- lift get
        lift $ put $ max currMax arg
        nextArg <- respond (even arg)
        loop nextArg

client :: (Proxy p, Monad m) => Client p Int Bool m ()
client = runIdentityP loop
    where loop = go 1
          go i = do
            isEven <- request i
            go $ if isEven
                then i `div` 2
                else i * 3 + 1
```

Currently the client always sends `Int`, and receives `Bool`. However, I want the client to also be able to query for the highest value that the server has seen so far. So I also need communication of sending `()` and receiving `Int`. I could encode this as the client sending `Either Int ()`, and receiving `Either Bool Int`. However, I'd like to ensure that the two aren't mixed - sending an `Int` always gets a `Bool` response.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why wouldn't Either work? If you send an Either to the server you can pattern match on the Left or Right cases and send an appropriate Left or Right back.

Comment: @Dwilson: He wants to statically ensure that sending `Int` always returns a `Bool`. Using `Either` would move this check to runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you want a pipeline to have two separate interfaces you have to nest the `Proxy` monad transformer within itself.  That means you want the type:

```
twoInterfaces
    :: (Monad m, Proxy p1, Proxy p2 )
    => () -> Int -> Server p1 Int Bool (Server p2 () Int m) r
twoInterfaces () n = runIdentityP . hoist runIdentityP $ do
    x <- respond A        -- Use outer interface
    y <- lift $ respond B -- Use inner interface
    ...
```

Given the following two clients for each interface:

```
client1 :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => () -> Client p Int Bool m r
client2 :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => () -> Client p ()  Int  m r
```

You would connect them to the two server interfaces using:

```
oneInterface () = runProxy (twoInterfaces () >-> client1)

main = runProxy (client1 >-> oneInterface)
```

To learn more about this trick, read the [Branching, zips, and merges](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.3.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html#g:17) section of the current tutorial.

You can also do it the other way around, too.  You can have a `Client` with two separate interface and hook up two different `Server`s.  This may or may not fit your problem better.

Note that this will get much simpler in `pipes-4.0.0` (currently on Github), where the types will be much more concise and you won't need `runIdentityP`:

```
twoInterfaces
    :: (Monad m) => () -> Int -> Server Int Bool (Server () Int m) r
twoInterface () n = do
    x <- respond A
    y <- lift $ respond B
   ...

client1 :: (Monad m) => () -> Client Int Bool m r
client2 :: (Monad m) => () -> Client ()  Int  m r
```

Comment: I had to change the second (pipes 4.0.0) snippet a bit to compile, by expanding the inner `Server () Int m` to `Proxy x y () Int m`, because (by my understanding) there's no way to have a partially applied type synonym with GHC

Comment: @ajp You can also use `Server'` to get it to work, too.  Every polymorphic type synonym has a concrete one that doesn't require being fully applied to all type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use two pipelines, tailored to your two use cases. One server would return a `Bool`, the other would return an `Int`. One client would accept a `Bool`, the other would accept an `Int`. The two clients would actually be `Pipe`s. One would return a `Left Int`, the other would return a `Right Bool` (or vice versa). The two servers could be passed in an `IORef` or something of the sort. You could then use this to keep track of the maximum value. A `Pipe` taking `Either Int Bool` at the end of the two clients could be used to do something with both the `Left` and `Right` cases returned by the clients.